# How do I color tiles based on this?

Tags: java, swing, colors

I'm currently trying to create a Give up button that colors all the tiles based on certain conditions. My program generates numbers:

let's say 25 5 6 7
This numbers are then placed in

```
<List>String numberTracker= new ArrayList<String>();
```

(I converted them to a string)

```
{25,5,6,7}
```

My program will then build 5 tiles and place each digit in each tile
2 5 5 6 7

To build tiles I import Shape and create a class tile that has shape, color and position in it that also contains `setTile`, `getTile`, `getColor`, `setColor`, `getPosition` and `setPosition`.

To keep track of of the the tiles, I keep them in

```
List<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<tile>();
```

To keep track and place the numbers in the tile I use

```
List<String> numberString= new ArrayList<String>;
```

To generate a `Color` I use `tile.changeCoulour()` which increments after each use

so if we go back to my previous example of 25 5 6 7
The tiles are created with

```
List<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<tile>();
```

The string numbers inside each tile with

```
List<String> numberString= new ArrayList<String>;
```

each tile has 1 digit as I said, 2 5 5 6 7 (they are all strings and placed with `drawString()`)

```
{2,5,5,6,7}
```

I need to somehow create a condition where 25 ( contained in 2 different tiles)  will be the same color where the rest of the tiles will be different

```
for (Tile item: tiles) {
    int position = item.getPosition();
    if (numberString.get(position) == numberTracker.get(position)) {
        item.setColor(tile.changeColour());
        repaint();
    } else {


    }
}
```

In that code I tried to equal the tile position to numberString position and then to itemTracker and if its the same it will change colour. However, I have trouble with the else statement

Comment: Use a `Map`?  Map each number to one or more tiles, this way you more easily look them up. You could also map the colors the same way

Comment: Please be sure to check the preview carefully before posting questions. E.G. things like `<String>` will vanish unless using code formatting. On that subject: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic idea is as follows: keep advancing the pointer to tiles and change the color when a new number (from those initially entered) is encountered.

```
int ind=0;
for(i=0 to numberTracker.size()-1) {
  String s=numberTracker.get(i);
  Color nextColor=....
  for(j=0 to s.length()-1) { tile(ind).setColor(nextColor); ind++; }
}
```

This will give for example the tiles {2, 5, 5 ,6 ,7} the colors {Red, Red, Green, Blue, Colorx}.